# Svchost.exe become resource hungry process

Tags: windows-7, svchost

I my windows 7 computer i found that my computer is hanging. then i open Taskmanager and saw that svchost.exe is taking 3,456,124kb of ram. this thing does`nt happen before. i also observed that when i run windows update it takes double of ram mentioned above. Even i had tried to kill this process as a result windows 7 starts to look like windows xp , windows update stops and again this process starts with same amount of ram usage what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I troubleshoot high 'svchost.exe' usage in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/91867/how-do-i-troubleshoot-high-svchost-exe-usage-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has released hotfixes and update patches for Windows 7 which addresses these memory leaks.  Please download and install from the following links:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2889748

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265

Comment: High memory usage by the Svchost.exe process after you install Windows Management Framework 3.0 on a Windows-based computer.how to check Windows Management Framework 3.0 is installed?