# Windows 10 svchost using 24 gigs of memory

Tags: windows, virtual-memory, memory-leaks, svchost

On windows 10 one of our users is getting a virtual memory error. Upon investigation, svchost is using 24 gigs of memory. When I do a memory dump and run a memory analysis using windows debugging tools, it shows that none of the treads or loaded modules are using more than a few hundred megabytes. The total of all of the memory all threads are using is about a gigabyte, yet it has 24 gigabytes of committed memory.

What could possibly be using this?
If I stop each service one by one, no individual service frees the gigabytes of memory used, but if I kill the svchost process, it respawns itself and starts back at a reasonable 200 MB. It takes about a week of the PC being on for memory usage to get this high.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I troubleshoot high 'svchost.exe' usage in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/91867/how-do-i-troubleshoot-high-svchost-exe-usage-in-windows-7)

Comment: Update your question.  What build of Windows 10 are you using?  Use `winver` to determine this information.  This a standard Windows 10 image?  You seem to indicate, this issue only happens for a single user, so what is unique about the image you used on their machine?  How much is virtual memory configured?  Are you allowing the system to manage the setting?  If you boot into a minimal boot configuration and wait a week, does the behavior still happen?  Have you tried to simply reimage the system? Update your question to include all this vital information required to answer your question